# Assign Value of Named URL to a Variable in Django Templates

Tags: django

In my Django template I need to assign the value of a names url into a variable within a with block so I can use it in multiple places.

I need to achieve something like this:

```
{% for tag in post.tags.all %}
    {% with tagabs={%url showtag tag%} %}
          <li><a href="{{tagabs}}">#{{tag}}</a></li>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

But obviously that doesn't work and would end up with a parsing error. The above example is a simple scenario where I could just have {%url showtag tag%} instead of {{tagabs}} and remove the with block. But in my scenario the tagabs value I need to use it in several places and within an if statement for comparison.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you give slightly more info on the bigger problem please?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Why create a new template tag/filter if the feature is in core?

Look the samples at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

```
{% url 'path.to.view' arg arg2 as the_url %}

<a href="{{ the_url }}">I'm linking to {{ the_url }}</a>
```

and

```
{% url 'path.to.view' as the_url %}
{% if the_url %}
  <a href="{{ the_url }}">Link to optional stuff</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, definitely much more elegant than a new tag. Thanks!

Comment: The statement which `as` is not rendered (it's how it works). Later on you can use that variable.

Answer (score -4):

I think you'll have to either create your own [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to manage this problem or create the necessary data in the view and pass it in to the template.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do maybe [including](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) another template and sending in your defined variable could do it, but I doubt it.

The thinking behind Djangos templating system is to make it so there isn't very much logic in the templates. And thus it's back to either preparing the data you need for output in the view or making a template tag.

Comment: Because the way I understood the question didn't match up with any core behavior I know of. The way it came off to me was someone trying to make complex operations in the view and not just simply naming a URL.