# Jinja2 "as" tag not working?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have this code in `index.html`:

```
{% url 'cronjobs:remove-job' as remove_job_url %}
```

And I want to use it further down in the same HTML file multiple times, e.g.:

```
<a href="{{ remove_job_url }}">Remove job</a>
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16221183/7330952), I think I got everything right. However, the variable `remove_job_url` is null. Nothing is printed to the anchor tag.

I have loaded the Jinja2 into my `settings.py -> TEMPLATES` as described [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render), yet it does not seem to work. Any ideas what might be wrong?

(this also happens when I use the `{% trans ... as trans_var %}` tag, the `trans_var` is again - empty)

Comment: Django templates are not the same thing as Jinja2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use Django template syntax in a Jinja2 template. The template syntax is related, *but no the same*. You need to use [Jinja2 assignment syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments) instead.

```
{% set remove_job_url = url('cronjobs:remove-job') %}
```

Note the `url()` *call*. See the [*Url reversing* section](https://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/#_url_reversing) of the Django-jinja integration documentation.